# std::is_pod vs subclassing

Tags: c++, c++11

Could someone please help me understand why the following code does not compile (g++ 4.8). My understanding is that one could initialize a POD

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct my_int
{
  int val_;
};
struct B : public my_int
{
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::is_pod<my_int>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::is_pod<B>::value << std::endl;
  const my_int v = { 123 };
  //const B v2 = { 123 }; // does not compile with g++ 4.8.

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation is:

```
g++ -std=c++11 t.cxx
t.cxx: In function 'int main()':
t.cxx:24:21: error: could not convert '{123}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const B'
   const B v = { 123 };
                     ^
```

EDIT:

Thanks to everyone answer I now understand the concept of aggregate initialisation. I missed the fact that aggregate could not have base class. Therefore my current implementation plans needs to be changed. I wanted to do something like:

```
template < typename T >
struct base_class
{
  int val_;
};
struct MyInt : public base_class<int>
{
  void Func1() {}
};
struct MyDouble : public base_class<double>
{
  void Func2() {}
};
```

I'll rework the above code to avoid the use of subclass to introduce special member functions, while avoid code duplication.

Comment: You could add a non-trivial **non-default** ctor like `B::B(int p) : my_int(p) {}` which retains `B`'s status as a POD but allows the initialization `const B v2 = {123};`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

Take the following with a grain of salt as it is my interpretation of things. I am by no means an expert. (Also I have some doubts about the aggregate - initializer list relation which I stated here.)

**Answer**

As far as I can tell this is not possible because the aggregate initialization of v2 would be applied to the non aggregate class type B.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189821/420683) you can take that aggregates must not have a base class,
which makes `B` a non aggregate and therefore not initializable by a brace enclosed initializer list.

On the other hand `std::is_pod` might not do what you think it does because the POD definition has changed in C++11. Therefore, it does not give you a hint if the type that is a POD can be initialized with such an aggregate initializer.

**Addition**

I am mainly discussing aggregate initialization here, but the more general term for this is [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) which is less restrictive. However, checking all the cases I found in the linked resource there is no possibility to do list initialization either
because (following the resource's list of effects of an initializer list):

- the initializer list is not empty
- `B` is not an aggregate
- `B` is not a specialization of `std::initializer_list`
- `B` has no

  - constructor taking an initializer list
  - constructor fitting the signature of the list
- `B` is no reference type
- `B` cannot be copy-initialized from `123` and not direct-initialized because there is no constructor taking an int
- `B` is not value-initialized because the initializer list ist not empty

Comment: Visual C++ 2013 RC backs up your theory:


Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.60610.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
test.cpp(18) : error C2552: 'v2' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with ini
tializer list
        'B' : Types with a base are not aggregate

Comment: @jschroedl: clang 3.3 said something similar (`non-aggregate type 'const B' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
`)but I dislike using compiler outputs for the reasoning, because they may deviate from the standard.

Comment: Maybe you should link to the [C++11 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7189821/420683) to the same question instead for a definition of aggregates. Besides that, I agree that with your analysis of the Standard ([dcl.init.list]/3). `const my_int v = { 123 };` is list-initialization, but it does not do (resolve to) aggregate-initialization because `my_int` is not an aggregate. The only available ctor are the default ctor and copy/move ctor, but those cannot be used with an argument of type `int`. The object to be initialized is of class type and no reference. Ergo the program is ill-formed.

Comment: @DyP: Thanks for the link (I changed it in my answer, I should have scrolled further down :). The point I was trying to make was that the OP was apparently trying to do aggregate initialization which is not possible here. Then I realized that it might be possible by list initialization and wrote the addition to rule that one out too.